# Inline editing row

Tags: jqgrid, inline-editing

I'm starting with jqGrid now and there are some issues that I can't understand.
I'm doing a grid to be inline editable, but it just edit the 1st row. If I click in any row, it edit just the first row. I don't know what is going on, if somebody could tell me how to do it step-by-step, it would help me a lot.

This is a part of my code:

```js
$(function(){
    var lastSel;
    $("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'php.php', 
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'POST', 
    colNames:['ac_n_quad', 'ac_l_circ', 'ac_n_circ', 'ac_fin_g', 'ac_pot', 'ac_volt', 'ac_n_polos', 'ac_t_prot', 'ac_v_prot', 'ac_cabo',
    'ac_fd', 'ac_fp', 'ac_ctr', 'ac_pot_a', 'ac_pot_b', 'ac_pot_c', 'ac_pos_1', 'ac_pos_2', 'ac_calc'], 
    colModel :[ 
      {name:'ac_n_quad', index:'ac_n_quad', width:110, align:'right', editable:true, key:true},
      {name:'ac_l_circ', index:'ac_l_circ', width:65, align:'right', editable:true},
      {name:'ac_n_circ', index:'ac_n_circ', width:120, align:'right', editable:true, key: true},
      {name:'ac_fin_g', index:'ac_fin_g', width:60, align:'right', editable:true},
      {name:'ac_pot', index:'ac_pot', width:55, align:'right', editable:true},
      {name:'ac_volt', index:'ac_volt', width:60, align:'right', editable:true},
      {name:'ac_n_polos', index:'ac_n_polos', width:100, align:'right', editable:true},
      {name:'ac_t_prot', index:'ac_t_prot', width:100, align:'right', editable:true},
      {name:'ac_v_prot', index:'ac_v_prot', width:70, align:'right', editable:true},
      {name:'ac_cabo', index:'ac_cabo', width:60, align:'right', editable:true},
      {name:'ac_fd', index:'ac_fd', width:55, align:'right', editable:true},
      {name:'ac_fp', index:'ac_fp', width:55, align:'right', editable:true},
      {name:'ac_ctr', index:'ac_ctr', width:60, align:'right', editable:true},
      {name:'ac_pot_a', index:'ac_pot_a', width:70, align:'right', editable:true},
      {name:'ac_pot_b', index:'ac_pot_b', width:70, align:'right', editable:true},
      {name:'ac_pot_c', index:'ac_pot_c', width:70, align:'right', editable:true},
      {name:'ac_pos_1', index:'ac_pos_1', width:70, align:'right', editable:true},
      {name:'ac_pos_2', index:'ac_pos_2', width:70, align:'right', editable:true},
      {name:'ac_calc', index:'ac_calc', width:65, align:'right', editable:true}],
    cmTemplate: { align: 'center', editable: true },

    onSelectRow: function(id){
        if(id && id !== lastSel){
            $(this).restoreRow(lastSel);
            lastSel = id;
        }
        $(this).editRow (id, true);
    },
    prmNames: {ac_n_quad: "id"},
    editurl:'clientArray',
    autowidth: 'true', 
    height: 'auto', 
    rowNum: 10, 
    rowList: [10,20,30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
    sortname: 'ac_n_quad, ac_n_circ',
    sortorder: 'asc', 
    pager: '#pager', 
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,  
    caption: 'Table circ_69' 
    });

    jQuery('#list').jqGrid('gridResize');
    jQuery('#list').jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
             edit: true,
             add: true,
             del: true,
             search: false,
             refresh: false
    });
});
```

Comment: So when you select any rows other then the first or fourth they do not become editable in the grid?

Comment: No. When I select any row just the first become editable in the grid.

Comment: Do you see your id's changing as you select different rows? your Id in your onSelectRow should be the rowId of the selected row.

Comment: Thanks @Mark I saw what I was doing wrong... I didn't have an id to control the rows. The id that I defined before has more than one value, so it's because of this that it was not working... Thanks for your help :D Best Regards :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many errors in your code. The most important is the usage of `key: true` for more as one column. One can see that you included the property in definition of **two** columns `'ac_n_quad'` and `'ac_n_circ'`. When jqGrid fill the grid it uses `<table>` for the body of the grid, `<tr>` for rows and `<td>` for cells on the grid. It's important to understand that jqGrid **always** assign some `id` attribute to every `<tr>` (for rows). HTML don't permit to have duplicates of `id` on one HTML page. If you use `key: true` for some column then jqGrid assign internal option `keyIndex` to the index of the column in `colModel` array which has `key: true` option. In your case I think that jqGrid will use **the last** column with `key: true`. So the values from `'ac_n_circ'` column will be used as ids.

If you have duplicate values in `'ac_n_circ'` column then you will have many different very strange effects (which are distinguish in different web browsers). For example if you click on one row then another row could be selected. You can have also different strange effects during editing too.

Because you use `prmNames: {ac_n_quad: "id"}` (it's also wrong. correct will be `prmNames: {id: "ac_n_quad"}`) then I can suspect that `ac_n_quad` is the real unique id. So you should use `key: true` only in `ac_n_quad` column and you have to remove the property from any other columns (`'ac_n_circ'`).

Additionally you can reduce and simplify the code. Default values of properties of elements of `colModel` are described in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) (see "Default" column in the table). For example default values of `width`, `align`, `editable` are 150, "left" and false. You use `align:'right', editable:true` in all columns and you use `width:70` most frequently. So you can use

```js
cmTemplate: { align: 'right', editable: true, width:70 }
```

instead of `cmTemplate: { align: 'center', editable: true }` which you use now. It allows you to reduce `colModel` to

```js
colModel: [
    {name:'ac_n_quad', width:110, key:true},
    {name:'ac_l_circ', width:65},
    {name:'ac_n_circ', width:120},
    {name:'ac_fin_g', width:60},
    {name:'ac_pot', width:55},
    {name:'ac_volt', width:60},
    {name:'ac_n_polos', width:100},
    {name:'ac_t_prot', width:100},
    {name:'ac_v_prot'},
    {name:'ac_cabo', width:60},
    {name:'ac_fd', width:55},
    {name:'ac_fp', width:55},
    {name:'ac_ctr', width:60},
    {name:'ac_pot_a'},
    {name:'ac_pot_b'},
    {name:'ac_pot_c'},
    {name:'ac_pos_1'},
    {name:'ac_pos_2'},
    {name:'ac_calc', width:65}
]
```

If you have `index` value the same as the value of `name` value you can skip `index`. In the same way if you can skip `colNames` if it contains only values of `name` property of `colModel`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Oleg ! I realized this on the weekend, I was thinking and I understood one of the things that I did wrong. I don't have a "unique key", like you said I have 'ac_n_circ' and this have duplicate values, so I think I have to add one column in my database to be the index, because I don't have something that would be a index. Is correct to do this? I'm really thankful! :) Best Regards! :)

Comment: @mzs_newbie: You are welcome! Typically one have column with primary id in every column of the database. For example one can use `id int  PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY` as the definition of the column (or `id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` depend on which database you use). In any way if the data which you use for filling the grid have *no native id* you should just remove *key: true* from all column. In the case jqGrid will use 1, 2, 3, ... value as rowids.

Comment: @mzs_newbie: You are welcome! Sorry, but I didn't understood your example with squares and circuits. It can be **only one** primary key in the table, but you can use *composite* key which consist from the values of more as one columns. In the case you can for example add `id` attribute to the row of XML data which you generate on the server the value can be for example concatenation of the values from `'ac_n_quad'`, `'ac_n_circ'` and some separator like `'_'` between. If will inform jqGrid to use unique value constructed from your data.

Comment: Hummm thank you so much again! :)  I understood now! I'm using postgres. My problem is that I use "more than one column" like "primary key" I don't know if I'm explaining right to you. For example, I have number of squares and number of circuits... One square have one or more circuits. So I need to list the table for number of circuits and after for number of circuits... like that:  number of squares[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]  number of circuits [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2] (look at this like a table :).  So I created a index on database, because I didn't know how to proceed when I have something like this.

Comment: Yes! I think is this... composite key. I'm sorry to bother you but how can I do that?

Comment: @mzs_newbie: How looks the XML data which you returns from the server? You need just set **attribute** with the name `id` on the row of data. Alternatively you can add `<mykey>someCompositeValue</mykey>` element to the row and use `xmlReader: {id: "mykey"}`. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#xml_data). You should remove all `key: true` from `colModel` in the case.

Comment: Huuum ok, now I understood. Something like this: while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) { $s .= "<row id='"  .  $row['id'] .  "'>"; ... } Right?

Comment: @mzs_newbie: I don't use PHP, but I suppose that the code is correct.

Comment: @mzs_newbie: You can verify the results if you examine `id` attribute of `<tr>` elemens of the grid using Firebug or Developer Tools of IE (press F12) or Google Chrome.